# My android app shows inactive and in review on Google play console

Tags: android, flutter, google-play-console

I completed the flutter app for google play store.
I did the some tests and I click full rollout for production. It shows in review, and inactive.
Is there any problem? When my app (production) shows on google play store, does any one knows?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first production/beta release can take up to 7 days to approve. After that releases get approved within days.

Comment: my app has pre-register now. Is google play will do automatically normal registration ?

Comment: I think when I add countries on production page, it will be real production, right?

Comment: Yes, in this state, it will go through the review, but won't be served to any countries.

Comment: I am not very familiar with pre-registration, I'll look into it.

Comment: Yes, the registration will take effect after it is launched in the testers countries.